# How to update machine environment variables of a docker machine on mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to update the environment variables of a docker image using docker-machine on Mac.
No luck so far.
I checked issues including this one https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4651. Problem is
when I run

```
docker-machine env machine-staging
```

I get

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://*.*.*.*:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/b/.docker/machine/machines/machine-staging"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="machine-staging"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env machine-staging)
```

I tried the `unset` command which still didn't work.
I want to be able to add a new setting such as the `COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change variables on (a) your computer, (b) the remote Host on which your container runs, or (c) inside the container running on that host?

`docker-machine` just gives you a configuration for your local machine, allowing it to connect to the remote host. To change other local environment variables, run something like `export COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION=1.1` in the shell, or add it to your shell initialization (`/Users/<you>/.profile` usually).

The same basic approach works for modifying the environment on the host. For the container, you can add lines using the `ENV` command in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: it is mostly for the remote host, reason being that anytime I run a deploy command from circleci, I get this ```ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)
```